# Django multiple form submit

Tags: django, forms

I have following prototype:

[image]

And following djnago classes:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class AbstractItem(Models.model):
    container = models.ForeignKey('Container')
    class Meta:
            abstract = True

class Item1(AbstractItem):
    foo = models.CharField()

class Item2(AbstractItem):
    bar = models.IntegerField()
```

After a successful form submission, server should parse muliple forms (or one forms union), create multiple Item instanses and refer them to container instanse.

How to perform it in Django?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a formset.

See the [intro to formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/), and the docs specifically for [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: The main problem is dynamical changing of form in frontend (plus button).

Comment: Well, you specifically asked about how to make the server process multiple forms after submission. Changing forms in the frontend is just a matter of some Javascript.